# Convergence of a family piecewise linear approximants

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\epsilon$ be a small number 
$$f^\epsilon(p) = f(i\epsilon) + (p - i\epsilon) \frac{f((i+1)\epsilon) - f(i\epsilon)}{\epsilon},$$ with $i\epsilon \le p < (i+1)\epsilon.$

How do we prove that $f^\epsilon \to f$ uniformly as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: The convergence is uniform only $f$ is uniformly continuous, or if $f'$ is bounded.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Could you elaborate on that in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f'$ is bounded, i.e., there exists an $L>0$, such that
$$
|\,f'(x)|\le L,
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $x\in\mathbb R$, then $x\in[i\varepsilon,(i+1)\varepsilon]$, for some $i\in\mathbb Z$.
$$
f^\varepsilon (x)-f(x) = f(i\varepsilon) + (x - i\varepsilon) \frac{f((i+1)\varepsilon) - f(i\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}-f(x)
=-\int_{i\varepsilon}^x f'(t)\,dt+
\frac{x-i\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}\int_{i\varepsilon}^{(i+1)\varepsilon}f'(t)\,dt \\=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left((x-i\varepsilon)\int_{i\varepsilon}^{x}f'(t)\,dt
+(x-i\varepsilon)\int_{x}^{(i+1)\varepsilon}f'(t)\,dt-\varepsilon\int_{i\varepsilon}^xf'(t)\,dt\right)\\= \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left((x-i\varepsilon)\int_{x}^{(i+1)\varepsilon}f'(t)\,dt-\big((i+1)\varepsilon-x\big)\int_{i\varepsilon}^xf'(t)\,dt\right),
$$
and hence
$$
|\,f^\varepsilon (x)-f(x)|\le \frac{2L|x-i\varepsilon||(i+1)\varepsilon-x|}{\varepsilon}\le \frac{L\varepsilon}{2},
$$
and hence uniform convergence.

Comment: What if we assume $f \in C^2$?

Comment: I have not used it. However, I feel that uniform Lipschitz also works.

Comment: Alright; Also, what does it mean for $\{f^\epsilon\}$ to be Cauchy  with respect to the Lipschitz norm?

Comment: @Axel It is not a sequence of function, and hence I do not understand what it means

Comment: Indeed: neither do I.

Comment: Can we prove the same result only assuming $f$ bounded and uniformly continuous?